# Find a string surrounded by square brackets and *not* prefaced with a specific character

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to have a match with

> `[testing]`

but not

> `![testing]`

This is my query to grab a string surrounded by square brackets:
`\[([^\]]+)\]`

```
var match = /^[^!]*\[([^\]]+)\]/.exec(issueBody);
                    if (match) 
                    {
                        $ISSUE_BODY.selectRange(match.index, match.index+match[0].length);
                    }
```

and it works marvelously.
However, I have spent a good half hour on http://regexr.com/ trying to skip strings with a "!" in front, and couldn't.

**EDIT**: I'm sorry guys I didn't realize that there were operations that could not be supported by specific interpreters.  I am writing in Javascript and apparently lookbehind is not supported, I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression:
>   /(?

Sorry for wasting time :\

Comment: I'm using Javascript to execute the expression, and I don't think it's supported?

Comment: ok I modified my answer based on JS tag.

Comment: If you provide code you are working with, it will be easier to help you. Pure regex can't help *unless* you want to use a reverse-string technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use alternation:

```
(?:^|[^!])(\[[^\]]+\])
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fM2xU5/4)

Here `(?:^|[^!])` will match start of input OR any character that is NOT `!`

**Code:**

```
var re = /(?:^|[^!])(\[[^\]]+\])/gm;
var str = '![foobar123]\n[xyz789]';
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null)
    console.log(m[1]);
```

**Output:**

```
[xyz789]
```

Comment: This looks great!  One last thing: now when it matches, it grabs the character directly before the opening square bracket-- is there any way to not do that, and only select the square brackets and the text between?

Comment: Use captured group #1 for that as in this regex `/(?:^|[^!])(\[[^\]]+\])/`

Comment: When I put that in regexr it still shows as grabbing the first character, e.g. "a[shouldntgraba]"

Comment: That is because you're not printing captured group #1

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying.  I didn't understand the term captured group so I just skipped over that part in your comment, I'm sorry.  Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, where lookbehinds are not supported, you can use:

```
^[^!]*\[([^\]]+)\]
```

(with the multiline flag to match every start of a line)

See it on [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/3chos).

And here's a visualization from [debuggex.com](https://www.debuggex.com/r/DdnQo6TwdbuoXaEY):

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 1):

You can just use **capturing**:

```js
var re = /(?:^|[^!])(\[[^[\]]*])/g; 
var str = '[goodtesting] ![badtesting] ';
var m;
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    document.getElementById("r").innerHTML += m[1] + "<br/>";
}
```

```html
<div id="r"/>
```

The `(?:^|[^!])(\[[^[\]]*])` regex matches the start of string or any character other than a `!` (with a non-capturing group `(?:^|[^!])`) and **matches and captures** the substring enclosed with `[` and `]` that has no `[` and `]` inside (with `(\[[^[\]]*])`). When we need to get multiple matches, we need to use `RegExp#exec()` and access the captured groups using the indices (here, index 1).

Also, in JS, when you do not  need to check what is after the match, just a lookbehind without a lookahead, you can use a reverse string technique (use a lookahead with the reversed string):

```js
function revStr(s) {
    return s.split('').reverse().join('');
}
var re = /][^[\]]*\[(?!!)/g;  // Here, the regex pattern is reverse, too
var str = '![badtesting] [goodtesting]';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(revStr(str))) !== null) {  // We reverse a string here
  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML += revStr(m[0]); // and the matched value here
}
```

```html
<div id="res"/>
```

This is not possible with longer patterns but this one seems simple enough to go for it.

Comment: I just want to comment to say how awesome of an answer this is.  Unfortunately I marked anubhava's answer because it was less to implement and slightly more straightforward.  I appreciate your time on this answer

Comment: Just a sec, I forget to say that `if (m.index === re.lastIndex)      re.lastIndex++;` should be removed - it is redundant. See updated code. It is shorter than anubhava's and works the same way. That part of code is necesssary ONLY when the pattern can match empty strings. The one I suggest won't match empty strings.

Comment: Capturing means getting submatches using a pair of unescaped parentheses in the pattern. If you want to match digits inside angle brackets (like `<223>`), you can use `<(\d+)>` regex, and access the `223`  via Group 1.

Comment: anubhava changed his code to look as mine, but the `/m` modifier is still redundant. I'd still recommend to use a local `m` variable to avoid any interference with the main code.